# Use another element's ItemsSource property in a MultiBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, itemssource

I'd like to use the `ItemsSource` property from a particular element as one of the bindings in another element's `MultiBinding`.  Here's what I have so far:

```
<Label>
  <Label.Content>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{converters:myMultiValueConverter}">
      <Binding Path="PageIndex" />
      <Binding ElementName="anotherElement" Path="ItemsSource"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </Label.Content> 
</Label>
```

This works once (when the `ItemsSource` is initially set), but the binding fails to update when the `ObservableCollection` bound to the original element's `ItemsSource` property has items added or removed.  Is this kind of binding possible?

Comment: This really sounds and looks like something I would rather resolve at the ViewModel level. What does your `myMultiValueConverter` do?

Comment: Agree with @HighCore - you're putting logic in your view, essentially - you should boost that up to your ViewModel and handle it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a dummy binding (- you don't need the value -) like this to force the `MultiBinding` to be reevaluated:

```
<Binding ElementName="anotherElement" Path="ItemsSource.Count"/>
```

**Edit:** Just noticed a flaw: If you move items that would not register if that does not change the `Count` property in-between, maybe this is relevant for you. In that case you could bind to your own dummy for which you can fire change notifications upon `CollectionChanged` (not all that clean in any case though).

You might want to consider HighCore's suggestion, a `get`-only property that returns the calculated value for which you manually fire `PropertyChanged` in all places that it depends on is usually quite convenient.

Comment: Excellent, does just what I need.  In my specific case, I don't have to worry about items moving around - they'll only be added or removed.